# Request promise Unhandled rejection RequestError

Tags: node.js, facebook-graph-api, request

I am working on Facebook Graph Api using Node.js . i am using request-promise for this but when i send request for my response  i am getting this error "Unhandled rejection Request Error: Error". 
This is my code

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

const request = require('request-promise');


app.get('/url', (req, res) => {

  const userFieldSet = 'id,name,about,email';

  const options = {
    method: 'GET',
    uri: 'https://graph.facebook.com/v7.0/2423438197947713',
    params: {
      access_token:"my access token ",
      fields: userFieldSet
    }
  };
  request(options)
  .then(fbRes => {

    const parsedRes = JSON.parse(fbRes).data; 
    res.json(parsedRes);
  })


});






app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});
```

can anyone help me how to fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change params to qs

```
qs: {
      access_token:"my access token ",
      fields: userFieldSet
    }
```